# click event is not working for dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using google translator which creates dynamically translator bar,it has show original button (click on below image link).

I want to fire click event of "show original" button manually using javascript or jquery but is is not working, see some of the code snippets that i tried.

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#\\:1\\.restore").click();
    //or
    $("#\\:1\\.restore").on('click');
    //or
    $("#\\:1\\.restore").trigger('click',jQuery.Event( "click" ));
    //or
    document.getElementById(':1.restore').click();
})
```

imageURL: http://1drv.ms/1KhfLbo

Answer (score 2):

The event on `myBtn` is not fired and your event handler is not working. 
For dynamically added elements use `event delegation`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#myBtn', function() {
    // Your Code Here
});
```

To `trigger` event:

```
$("#\\:1\\.restore").trigger('click');
```

Comment: That was super quick! +1

Comment: @Tushar, congrats on reaching 5k :)

Answer (score 1):

You need delegate from a container such as `document`

```
$(document).on('click', '#\\:1\\.restore', function(){...}));
```

> I want to fire click event of "show original" button manually

Use

```
$('#\\:1\\.restore').trigger('click')
```

or

```
$('#\\:1\\.restore').click();//with no parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
Actually translate bar was inside iframe tag, so we need to select iframe (container) then any element inside that.

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $('#\\:1\\.container').contents().find('#\\:1\\.restore').click(); 
});
```